# Deleting Set of Indexs from NSMutableArray Efficiently

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have a set of Index  setOFIndex = {0,1,3,4}.
 now i want to remove this set of index from an NSMutableArray ?

what is the efficient method to do that ?

i have checked for any library method , but not able to find any.
 i cant use removeObjectAtIndex directly as at each deletion array will be shifted by one.

Comment: do you care about the order of the indexes?

Comment: @Anurag : what i was looking was generic code. Index can be in any order , and i think accepted answer will solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"one", @"a", @"two", @"b", @"three", @"four", nil];
NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1];
[indexes addIndex:3];
[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexes];
NSLog(@"array: %@", array);

// Output: array: (one, two, three, four)
```

[read the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: +1 For pointing out that an exact example of what OP wants exists *in the documentation*  Please, everyone...read the docs -__-

Comment: if the setOFIndex array comes as {0,1,4,5} , The above all logic will fail

Comment: @Ramshad: "if the setOFIndex array comes as {0,1,4,5} , The above all logic will fail" - This is *not correct*, see the documentation of `NSMutableIndexSet`: "The values in a mutable index set are always sorted, so the order in which values are added is irrelevant.".

Comment: Yes @MartinR , you are absolutely right .the above example will work fine . , thanks for correction .

Answer (score 3):

You should use NSMUTABleArray's method `removeObjectsAtIndexes:`
This is the code from documentation

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"one", @"a", @"two", @"b", @"three", @"four", nil];

NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1];

[indexes addIndex:3];

[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexes];

NSLog(@"array: %@", array);
```

I simply don't understand why people don't read documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
– removeObjectsInArray:
```

Convert your Indexset to array and then use above method.

EDIT:
 Very straight forward example from documentation.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"one", @"a", @"two", @"b", @"three", @"four", nil];

NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1];

[indexes addIndex:3];

[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexes];

NSLog(@"array: %@", array);
```

Comment: The argument of `removeObjectsInArray:` is an array of objects that are to be removed, not an array of indexes.

Comment: Yes, that is why next line is there :)

Comment: What I meant is: If you convert the index set to an array like e.g. `@[ @1, @4, @5 ]` then `removeObjectsInArray:` will remove the *objects* `@1, @4, @5` from the array, and not the elements with *index numbers* 1, 4, 5. - But if I understood your answer wrong then I beg your pardon and you can just ignore my comment.

Comment: @MartinR : i think you are right . this will not solve given problem

Comment: communication gap :(   I said to convert indexset to array means the value that the index set stores in the array, not the value itself. anyways he got a lot of anwers now. Its my fault that i only suggested the way, i should have coded then i would have got vote up and accepted. :(